# Cout starts printing at start of line when given a string

Tags: c++, string, std, cout, flush

I have a vector of strings in C++, named `lines`.

This line

```
std::cout << "First line: >" << lines[0] << "<" << std::endl;
```

prints ">irst line: >string_here" instead of "First line: >string_here<".

Why does cout start printing at the start of the current line after the string, and how can I resolve it? I also tried to flush after every cout but result was the same.

This is a full code that ilustrates my problem, **BEFORE it was solved**:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string.h>

std::vector<std::string> parse(char *buffer, const char *delimiter) {
    std::string buff(buffer);
    size_t pos = 0;
    std::string part;
    std::vector<std::string> parts;
    while ((pos = buff.find(delimiter)) != std::string::npos) {
        part = buff.substr(0, pos);
        parts.push_back(part);
        buff.erase(0, pos + 1);
    }

    parts.push_back(buff);

    return parts;
}

int main() {
    char *s;
    s = strdup("Many lines\r\nOf text");

    std::cout << s << std::endl;  // this should print the string how it is

    std::vector<std::string> lines;
    lines = parse(s, "\n");  // parsing the string, after "\n" delimiter
    // that was the problem, I should have parsed after "\r\n"

    std::cout << "First line: >"<< lines[0] << "<" << std::endl;  // output
}
```

Comment: what do you have in lines[0] ?

Comment: Can you reproduced it anywhere else? It seems system specific.

Comment: that is another strange thing, in lines[0] there is a string of exactly 31 chars, but when i print its length, it says 32. I checked, and the last one is NOT endline, just null.

Comment: i tried in ubuntu, i can try with ubuntu gnome in about 30 mins

Comment: *I checked, and the last one is NOT endline, just null*. What null? You mean `'\0'`?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. From the code you provide here alone there is no reason why it would produce the output you report

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's impossible to be sure without the full content of `lines[0]`, but my (educated) guess would be that `lines[0]` ends with `\r`, the carriage return character, so everything printed after `lines[0]` is printed a the beginning of the line.

Comment: Yes, that was the problem. I was trying to get the lines one by one, from a string with many, and I was parsing after "\n", when the delimiter is actually "\r\n". I will provide a full code to show the problem entirely

Comment: @VladIordache even if there is `\r` or something, I don't think you can have two `>` in output.

Comment: the first > was <, sorry